# How to make dragged element when dropped should be in center of droppable area

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a div

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 drop12">
    // content goes
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <p class="col-xs-4 drag12">
    // content goes
  </p>
</div>
```

My issue is how to make dragged element when dropped in droppable area should be in center of the droppable div using jquery-ui

```
$('.drag12').draggable();
$('.drop12').droppable();
```

Can check in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fefcn9nm/1/

Comment: And you can make a more detailed layout on such https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Hi alexandr after dropping the p tag, it should be in center both vertically and horizontally @AlexandrMalyita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/fefcn9nm/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var offsetCenter;

  $('.drop12').droppable();
  $('.drop12').on('drop', function( event, ui ) {
     var $divDrop = $(this);
     offsetCenter = {
       top: $divDrop.offset().top + $divDrop.height()/2,
       left: $divDrop.offset().left + $divDrop.width()/2
     }

     var diffLeft = offsetCenter.left - event.pageX,
            diffTop = offsetCenter.top - event.pageY;

      $(ui.draggable).css({
         left:  parseInt($(ui.draggable).css('left')) + diffLeft,
         top:  parseInt($(ui.draggable).css('top')) + diffTop
      })
  });

  $('.drag12').draggable();
})
```